# ReportViewer Expressions , character check

Tags: expression, reportviewer

I'd like to know if there is a way to check if there is a *comma ,* in the !field.Value.

I want to make these conversations:

*10,5 -> 10,50*
*900 -> 900,00*

To do that, I need to know if there is a *comma* in the field value and also how many characters are after the *comma*. Is it possible ?

Comment: can;t you just format the ifield.Value?

Comment: http://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/crystal-report-formatting-the-decimal-field-custom-styling/

Comment: The documentaion in *msdn* just shows some conditionals and booleans. Didn't find anything that I could use.

Comment: I'm using *ReportViewer* not *CrystalReport*. Here it doesn't have the *Format Object* option, but we have *expression*... I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at InStr(), Len(), and IIF(), I think they will get you what you want.

I don't have a way to test this where I am, but basically I think this expression will get you there:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!MyField.Value, ",") > 0,
 Fields!MyField.Value & LEFT("000000", (-1 *(2 - (Len(Fields!MyField.Value) - InStr(Fields!MyField.Value, ","))))),
 Fields!MyField.Value & ",00")
```

Here's the basic idea of the script:

```
If there is a comma in the field, 
then add x number of 0s onto the end of the field
    where x is 2 - (the length of the field - the position of the ',' in the string) * -1
else just return the field + ",00"
```

Comment: I'll try ! As  soon as I finish it i'll come back with the results. Thanks

Comment: I just made a couple corrections myself, so try the latest code if it doesn't work

Comment: part of it depends on whether InStr is 0 based or 1 based

Comment: Almost there, it turned the *800 -> 800,00 150 -> 150,00*  perfect !! But the *5.5 -> 5,5000*

Comment: Alright @PlayHardGoPro, I verified that InStr is 1-based, and updated the script accordingly.  That's probably why it wasn't working.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanaaanks a bunch o/